# AngularJS: How do I animate the text if $index changes?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-track-by

I have an app in angularjs which uses $interval() in background and requests datas form the database via PHP every seconds.

I then use track by $index which really helps on performance.

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users track by $index">
<td>{{user.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

But I want to change the text color for 1 second when the data for that `<td>` changes.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try

```
<td ng-style="{color:#000}">{{user.name}}</td>
```

keeping in mind that data will get reloaded every second.

Or 
you can track which data is being changed from controller  with condition and set a variable true or false based on that like

```
$scope.datachange = true;
```

then in view you can do

```
 <td ng-style="datachange && {color:#000}">{{user.name}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, instead of looking at the index changing, put an ng-class where you'd like the color to change like:

```
<tbody ng-class="{'changed-class': dataChanged}">
```

Then, after your data changes in the controller, change the value of $scope.dataChanged to true and then back to false a second later by injecting $timeout:

```
$scope.dataChanged = true;
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.dataChanged = false;
}, 1000);
```

And of course, add the changed-class in your css with the color you'd like the text to be when the change happens.